# program that will show a triangle with X's (as shown in description) using FOR loop

Tags: for-loop

The program has to show this using for loop

X
XX
XXX
XXXX
XXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX

Any advices?

Comment: Just google after a simple for-loop in the language you want. I would use a for loop with a integer, and as how big the integer is as much X I would write ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without completely giving you the answer, here's the general loop structure you could use (C#):

```
int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
     //Do something here
     for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
     {
         //Do something else here
     }
}
```